# Django database obfuscation, using angular ui-grid

Tags: javascript, django, database, security

In a Django application(using an angular ui-grid in a template), with default authentication, using Oauth2 and CSRF tokens for the forms, and a model with 40+ field names.

**How can you achieve obfuscation in a DRY manner or what's the best way with the least possible code, in order to map the front-end grid object fields to the back-end model table names?**

This is how I'm doing it right now(test model with a few fields), but i would appreciate input to know of a good way to follow DRY as much as possible and using db obfuscation;

In a Django view I'm getting this json string from an ajax post(it comes from the rows in the ui-grid, where I'm specifying the field names in the constructor):

```
data=[{"part_name": "part 1", "part_id": "1", "quantity": "233", "ticket": "32", "comments": "32"}{"part_name": "part 1", "part_id": "1", "quantity": "233", "ticket": "32", "comments": "32"}]
```

Then in order to insert into model:

```
grid=ast.literal_eval(data)


for d in grid:
    object_insert={}
    for key in d:
        object_insert[key]=d[key]
    order=Order_Detail(**object_insert)
    order.save()
```

I have to reveal table column names in javascript for this(or just add a prefix or sufix, but very guessable).

Comment: Obscuring your table names does not prevent you from adhering to DRY. Also, no reason your table names necessarily need to be in the client code to begin with. That said, your question is pretty opinion-based and probably not well-suited for SO as-written. Perhaps the question you should be asking, if you're concerned about it, is how you can achieve that obfuscation in a DRY manner or how to avoid putting table names in your client code.

Comment: got it, I am new to stackoverflow, i will follow your advice on better wording the question.. but i am not saying to show table names, just column names(the table  name is only in the backend view), one easy add on that comes to mind is just using a prefix or sufix , at least they're not the same, although easily guessable , just adds a little bit of obscuring.(i see the benefit for example in a front-end grid that has 40+ rows to save in a db)